# Cookie being set, or not set.? Cookie Set to Array()

Tags: php, cookies

So my cookie should be set this way.
Page One Cotains.

```
$filename=rand(1000,20000);
setcookie("rand",$filename,time()+120);
```

Then I try to recall the cookie and then it just gets bad. This is on Page two.
I try to recall the cookie like so;

```
$filename1=$_COOKIE["rand"];
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Then since print_r trys to echo all cookies my cookie decides it isn't going to play with anything, says leave, and spits back Array()

Like so;

```
Array()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: not enough info. Are you trying to get the cookie value in the same script execution as you set it? (you can't)

Comment: your print_r($_COOKIE);  is on a page after(not the same page) setcookie?

Comment: @CrayonViolent session's are not cookies

Comment: I assume you're trying to read the cookie before the 2 minutes have expired?

Comment: I ran your code with a little utility I have, and it works. Uh, did you copy and paste that? I ask because a semi-colon is missing.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.
EDIT; The semi colon still doesn't matter, on my server it's fixed, I just pasted it from a thread that I made on another forums.

Comment: it appears the be the rand() function. I tried it with sessions, and still nothing. I'll need to figure this out on my own then.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if this is what you're doing, but --

If you set the cookie and try to read the cookie during the same execution of the script, the $_COOKIE array will not yet be populated by the cookie. You won't see it till the next time the browser sends a request to the script.

Comment: Actually it's not, The point of setting the cookie was I could not find a way to post that specific variable to the next page, So on page1 the cookie would be set,  on page2, the cookie would then need to be retrieved.  :P Thanks for the input though, any other ideas.?

Comment: @RainbowdashTM if that's why your using cookies, you should actully be using sessions

Comment: Alright, but why isn't this working currently.? The code is fine correct?